# IE save target as for a pdf file

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, command-line, savefiledialog

In IE if i open any link of an pdf file it opens in the browser itself due to association. But i want it to open a save window asking user where to save(same as save target) using command line. How it can be done?

Comment: That should be in Internet Options for IE.  It's not a command line issue.

Comment: However if you right click the PDF link you can use the 'save target as' option.

Comment: @foxidrive I am not telling it as an issue. All browser designed to open pdf in browser itself. But i want a command line for IE which saves that file instead of opening in browser.

Comment: If you want to save a file from a web URL using the command line then you can use WGET which is a free tool to download.